# AWS Lambda + queue length

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can I use a Lambda to do something like send a million mails via SendGrid, by invoking the Lambda, asynchronously, a million times, in quick succession? Will all the queued requests fire, eventually, assuming that the life of the queue is 6 hours.([Link to AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html))

Answer (score 1):

Any requests that exceed your concurrent limit will queue until they are run (as long as they do not exceed the 6-hour limit).

With such high volumes, you should ask for an increase in your limit of concurrent lambda functions.

(And then get a lawyer, because sending one million emails is likely to be treated as spam.)

Comment: The business is already sending mails to the subscribers, but with a lot of extra infra - a DB & a RabbitMQ queue. I wanted to remove some of these moving parts. The AWS documentation does not specify queue length. Not sure why I got a -1 vote. I have done my research - wanted to know if someone has tried queuing a large number of lambda requests.